# Let $X= \lbrace x_{0} \rbrace$ and $Y$ is a compact subset of $M$. Then, $D(X,Y)=d(x_{0},y)$ for $y \in Y$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non empty subsets of a metric space $(M,d)$. On the other hand, we define

$$D(X,Y)=\mbox{inf} \lbrace d(x,y) \: | \: x \in X, \: y \in Y \rbrace.$$ My aim is to prove the subsequent claims.

(a) Let $X= \lbrace x_{0} \rbrace$, where obviously $x_{0} \in M$ and $Y$ is a compact subset of $M$. Then, $D(X,Y)=d(x_{0},y)$ for an element $y \in Y$.

(b) If both $X$ and $Y$, are compact subsets of $M$. Then  $D(X,Y)=d(x,y)$ for some a few $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.

To kick in into this problem I did a doodle to gain up some intuition into this problem. To my surprise both claim seems so natural but I havent figured out how to prove them. I mean, for (a) I need to show that $$D(x_{0}, Y)=\mbox{inf} \lbrace d(x_{0},y) \: | \: y \in Y \rbrace=d(x_{0},y)$$ for some $y \in Y$.  So take for instance $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $d$ the euclidean metric, and lets say $A= \lbrace  0 \rbrace$ and $B=[1,2]$ our compact subset, and so its easy to see the D(X,Y) is the distance from the exterior point, 0 , to $inf(B)= 1$. But im cannot  generalize this aoproach to prove the statement  (a) neither (b). Somehow I  need to use the fact $Y$ is compact so I can guarantee $inf(Y),sup(Y) \in Y$ ?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z=X\times Y$ is a compact subset of $M\times M.$ Define a function $D: Z \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ where $D((x, y)) = d(x, y).$ The distance between $X$ and $Y$ is the infimum of $D$ on $Z.$ Since $Z$ is compact, the infimum is actually achieved at some point $(x, y) \in Z.$

Comment: I loved your approach to the problem. So as $\lbrace x_{0} \rbrace$ is compact, we only need to prove (b) right? Also, we are assuming the fact that cartesian product of compact sets is compact and the funcrion $D:Z \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Am I right?

Comment: @Cos Yes, on the second, but we are not "assuming" it, it is very easy to prove that the function $D$ is continuous (it is continuous in both coordinates, and the product topology is exactly the one that makes such a function continous). Similarly, with compactness.